# Why isn't std::move a keyword in C++?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Obviously, move semantics/r-value references were a much needed addition in C++11.  One thing that has always bugged me though, is std::move.  The purpose of std::move is to transform an l-value into an r-value.  And yet, the compiler is perfectly happy to let you continue using that value as an l-value and you get to find out at runtime that you screwed up.

It seems like there is a missed opportunity to define move (or some other name) as a keyword (similar to *_cast) and actually have the compiler understand that the referenced value can no longer be used as an l-value here.  I'm sure there is some implementation work to do this, but is there some fundamental reason why this wasn't done?

Comment: "And yet, the compiler is perfectly happy to let you continue using that value as an l-value and you get to find out at runtime that you screwed up" - what are you talking about? If you try to use a `std::move` return value where an lvalue is required, you'll get a compilation error. Are you misunderstanding what happens when you try to use the moved-from object after it's been moved from?

Comment: Well, you get an xvalue, which is a glvalue but not an lvalue. Now many functions like operator= accept any glvalue where one might expect that they are restricted to lvalue, maybe that's the source of the confusion.

Comment: You can't tell at compile time whether a statement is trying to use a moved-from object. Making `std::move` a keyword wouldn't help.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, moved-from objects in are still objects.  They can be used.  They are usually in a defined state.

There are some optimizations you can do when you are willing to 'rip the guts' out of an object and use it elsewhere.  The C++ committee decided these optimizations should be done implicitly and automatically in a few cases; usually where elision was already permitted, but where it wouldn't work for whatever reason.

Then, the ability to explicitly do this was added.  Making this operation end the lifetime of its right hand side would complicate the lifetime rules of C++ to an extreme degree; rather than doing that, they noted they could be highly efficient *without complicating the lifetime rules of C++* and leaving them exactly as-is.

It turns out there are a handful of flaws in this; to this extent, C++20 may be adding some "move and destroy the source" operations.  In particular, a number of move-construction like operations are easier to write as nothrow if you can both move and destroy the source in one fell swoop.

Actually having it change the lifetime of automatic storage variables is not in the cards.  Even describing how such a change would work, let alone making sure it doesn't break anything horribly, would be a challenge.

A simple example of why having it *always* happen wouldn't be good might be:

```
Foo foo;
if (some_condition) {
  bar = std::move(foo);
}
```

the lifetime of `foo` is now a function of `some_condition`?  You'd either have to ban the above with that kind of construct, or go down a pit of madness you may never get out of.